# "likes for comments" database designing?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

i have database tables for `Posts` and `comments`.
i want to allow users to put a like or dislike for each comments and posts.
so..i have few ideas of doing this. please tell me either i am correct or not.

create  two additional columns in comments table.

```
likes | liked_uids
```

if a person clicks on like button then add +1 for the current value in `likes` field, else add -1 for current value.
and add user's id to `liked_uids` field as a sting separated by "-" dashes.
then next time i can get that string to an array and check that,
either current user id has recorded or not. if user id is, then can decide that user have participated for liking.

but i have little problem on this structure, that what will if more than one user going to like at once for a post ? then i may lose some data from `liked_uids` string (one last uid).

so please tell me what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: you don't want to save your information as a separated string in a field. That's never (ok, almost never) an option. Just don't. ever. trust me :) ... If your data means multiple things (userids) can belong to one thing (the thing that is liked) you need a one-to-many connection, so this means an extra table. Problem is, explaining how to do this and why is basically a "how to design a database" 101, so a bit too big of a scope I think. Try to read up on normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create like this->

```
id type ('comment/like') uid comment      post_id
1   comment               1   good post    100
2    like                 2   null         101
3   like                  1  null          102
4   comment               3  bad post      104
```

It is not recommended to store like count.If you want to count the likes for a particular post:

```
select count(*) from tableName where post_id = 100
```

Storing user id separted by any delimiter will land you on problems, Hence not **recommended**. It will be tidies job to update or retrieve if your store user id using delimiter.

If you want to see if particular user is liked a particular post or not, use below query:

```
select count(*) from tableName where post_id = 100 AND uid =1
```

Comment: thanks. dont you think that when table fills with thousands of rows with the time, will not this effect to the sites efficiency ?

Comment: Mysql can handle record more than what you are expecting. And what you have table right now will land you with problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a separate **Likes** table with columns **Likes, DisLikes, Likes_UID, DisLikes_UID** and mapping table for comments and likes ex: **Comments_Likes** and posts and likes **Posts_Likes**

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing way too slow on my mobile ^^ Everything already answered.

I never did anything that is similar, but I wouldn't add the two columns in the comment table. I would rather create a new table like "votes" and it would have following columns.

```
comment_ref | like | user_ref
```

Every time someone likes a comment you insert a new line there. You could also make the combination comment_ref and user_ref as a key, so you can't insert it twice.

In the end you would just make a query as such to get the votes of a single comment.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE comment_ref = 123
```

Comment: Instead of saving only a 1 for a like you could save a 1 for "like" and a 0 for "dislike". In that case you can write a query like SELECT(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE like = 1 AND comment_ref = 123) as Likes, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE like = 0 AND comment_ref = 123) as Dislikes